# How can I talk to the goth kids if I sold part of the goth set?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

So, I have done everything I need to to start the DDR session with the goth kids. However, I accidentally sold one of the goth clothes. The guy at the U-Stor-It doesn't seem to have any more to sell and I can't buy them back from the person I sold them to. Because of this, I cannot re-equip the goth clothes. Is there a way to proceed from here?

Answer (score 4):

go to a store that has buyback and get it back.

Comment: Might not work if they saved and quit for a while since the buyback option is session/time based.